# How to fix "ConnectionError: Connection is closed" on Node.js with MSSQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, request, pool

I'm having issues with SQL server. Every time I try to run this server and get the results from database, I got this error message:

```
ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
  ...
code: 'ECONNCLOSED'
```

I can't find any way to fix this, is there something missing I should have on my JS files?

connection.js

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

const dbSettings = {
    user: '******',
    password: '******',
    server: "DESKTOP-*****\\SQLEXPRESS",
    database: 'webstore',
    driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
    options: {
        encrypt: true,  // for azure
    }
}

export async function getConnection() {
    try {
       
        const pool = await sql.connect(dbSettings, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }); 

        return pool;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
}
```

products.controller.js

```
import {getConnection} from '../database/connection';

export const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
    
    const pool = await getConnection();
    const result = await pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM Products');
    
    console.log(result);

    res.json('products');
};
```

Comment: If something takes a callback it most likely doesn't return a promise

Comment: Have you tried `await sql.connect(dbSettings)` without the callback?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I did but I'm having another error message: 

return pool.request().query('SELECT * FROM Products');
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'request')


Do you know anything wrong with request function?